# allocate memory with cudaMalloc

Tags: cuda

If I declare a variable:

```
define SIZE = 900; // width and height of an image

float ** abc;
```

So if I want to allocate the memory for it on GPU, should I allocate it like this?

```
cudaMalloc(&abc, SIZE * SIZE * sizeof(float));
```

Because I got a warning: integer operation result is out of range.

If I declare it like this:

```
cudaMalloc(&abc, SIZE * sizeof(float));
```

Then it it fine, I dont know whether with array 2 dimension, what should I allocate?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I would ike to help you, but your question is really unclear, please clean it up.

Comment: I think it should be clear, no?

Comment: No, you declare 'abc' and then use a 'GPU_input' and a 'SIZE' which we have no idea what they are. We can only try to guess. That error has nothing to do with CUDA anyway.

Comment: What is 'abc' and how does it correspond to the cudaMalloc call? what is in the SIZE variables? and who are you multiplying them? could it be that you are trying to malloc something in two dimensions?

Comment: Hi, that is my mistake. I have updated it! I am sorry. thanks guys!

Comment: `define SIZE = 900;` make no sense - you want either `#define SIZE 900` or better yet `const size_t SIZE = 900;`

Comment: 129 questions so far and you've accepted fewer than half of them ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Does this code give you the same warning?

```
  const size_t SIZE = 900;
  float *abc;
  cudaMalloc((void **)&abc, SIZE * SIZE * sizeof(float));
```

Try exactly this code, not something like it... if this isn't working, my guess is that there is a serious problem that's not your fault.

Why would you declare abc to be a doubly indirect pointer to float? malloc() and cudaMalloc() only allocate contiguous chunks of memory... if you want to interpret abc as a two-dimensional array, you'll have to work out the logic for doing so (translate to/from two-dimensional and linear indices) on your own. What you're asking nvcc to do is to allocate 3,240,000 bytes of memory for a float*, which should only need 4 bytes to store.

Comment: Furthermore, if you want to do a 2D allocation, you almost certainly want a "pitched" allocation (use cudaMallocPitch()), so the CUDA driver can pad the allocation in a way that is palatable to whatever hardware you are running on.

Answer (score 1):

cudaMalloc does not allocate 2-dimensional array, you can translate 1-dimensional array to a 2-dimensional one, or you have to first allocate a 1-dimensional **pointer** array for float **abc, then allocate float array for each pointer in **abc, like this:

```
float ***abc;
float ***h_abc = malloc(SIZE * sizeof(float*));
cudaMalloc(&abc,SIZE * sizeof(float*));
for(int i = 0 ; i < SIZE ; i++ ){
     cudaMalloc(&(h_abc[i]), SIZE * sizeof(float)):
}
cudaMemcpy(&abc,h_abc,SIZE * sizeof(float*));
```